# Swift: What does this statement in Extension mean?

Tags: swift, protocols, extension-methods

Here is a swift protocol and extension to convert a range to an array:

```
protocol ArrayRepresentable {
    typealias ArrayType

    func toArray() -> [ArrayType]
}

extension Range : ArrayRepresentable {
    func toArray() -> [Element] {
        return [Element](self)
    }
}
```

I don't understand the meaning of the following line:

```
return [Element](self)
```

What does it return? How does it manage to append the element to an existing array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it creates a new array with each of the elements in the range.

You could create an empty array of Ints, for example, using `[Int]()`.

In this case `Element` is the type of the items "contained" in the Range.  When it calls the arrays `init` it passes the range itself as a parameter and that initializer walks through the elements in the range and adds each to the array.